# Eclipse IDE -- Type safety: unchecked invocation

Tags: java, eclipse, gson

I don't understand why the Eclipse IDE is giving me a "Type safety: unchecked invocation" warning on this method.

```
    public static Object decode(String _json, Class _class) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.fromJson(_json, _class);
    }
```

I have heavily redacted the code to just illustrate the issue. The code works fine; its just Eclipse that is having a cow.  The "return" line is the one with the warning.

As is, the method is just a wrapper for [Gson's object instantiation method](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class)).  **Am I doing something wrong? Do I need to handle something differently?**

Is it because the return is of Type Object?  It HAS to be generic like that to be able to return all types of classes, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the Class argument `_class`.

Class needs to have a generic parameter: `Class<? extends Type>` means any Class that extends "Type" (replace Type with your required common super class)

You can specify `Class<?>` which is the same as `Class<? extends Object>` and means any class - and the warning should go away

Answer (score 0):

> Warning: Unchecked invocation execute(new CallableStatementCreator(){}, new CallableStatementCallback(){}) of the generic method execute(CallableStatementCreator, CallableStatementCallback) of type   JdbcTemplate.

Here is the answer How to supress the warning:

```
jdbcTemplateObject.execute(new CallableStatementCreator() {                 
                public CallableStatement createCallableStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {                  
                    cs= con.prepareCall("{?=call Package(?)}");                             
                    cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER); 
                    cs.setString(2,argument);
                    cs.executeUpdate();             
                    int return_Value = cs.getInt(1);                    
                    logger.info("Package Return Value : "+return_Value); 
                    return cs;
                }
            }, new CallableStatementCallback<Object>() {                
                public Object doInCallableStatement(CallableStatement cs) throws SQLException {
                    cs.execute();
                    return null;
                }

            });
```

Adding `<Object>` next to `CallableStatementCallback` will **eliminate warnings**